# On Updatepanel update, everything outside the updatepanel disappears

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Apologies for such a broad, sweeping question, but I can't really give specific code examples because as far as I can tell from research this problem is unique to the particular page I'm working on and if I knew what to do to replicate it then I'd most likely be able to fix it.

I have an asp.net vb (v3.5 using the ajaxcontroltoolkit v4) page essentially binding some straight forward SQL database data to a gridview.

The gridview's in an update panel and whenever I do anything that causes a postback inside the update panel, everything outside the update panel vanishes. The update panel IS updating correclty.

There's no conditional updating, just an 'out of the box' update panel.

All other ajax functionality is working correctly, such as filtered textbox extenders and validation with callout extenders, so I don't think it's a basic script reference error.

I'm making use of javascript and jquery to modify controls on the fly that are within the updatepanel.

It was a standalone page for development but for testing this problem I put it into a contentplaceholder on a masterpage. Now on updating, everything else in the contentplaceholder disappears, leaving the masterpages header etc present.

If you haven't come across this particular problem before, can you think of how I could go about debugging it?

If you have any ideas at all, it might be enough to set me down the right path.

Many thanks.

Comment: Well, at that point, i would try commenting things and testing. Maybe starting on what's inside the update panel, and all the javascript logic. Commenting things one by one, just letting something on the page to trigger a postback and see what happens. You could also try to think what is there on that page that is not really usual, and start by taking those things off.

Comment: Additionally, you can use the chrome network profiler to observe what's coming from the server when you make a postback. Every updatepanel's content that will update after the postback should be on the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for taking the time to make suggestions Mt. Schneiders.

In the end...haha wow, embarrassing... I've been doing this for the best part of 6 years now and I was closing my updatepanel before closing a div that started above the panel.

Simple fix. Yay! Thanks again.

Comment: I can't mark this as the answer for two days, I'll try to remember!

Comment: I read your note and realized I had the same problem. I think in the end we can say that a partial postback shouldn't be dropping controls on the page. if so, there's a Div problem somewhere.